# Change Google Maps direction line to icons

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to change the default Google Maps direction line, the blue line that you are meant to follow, into a series of icons?

So instead of having a blue line showing the route on the map, I'd like to replace this with a series of small icons.

Or, if that isn't possible, can I place icons along the route in say 1km increments?

I see plenty of examples of replacing the start and end markers but not of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  One option:

[PolylineOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions) to the [DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions), you can also apply [symbols](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols) to the Polyline
([example using a "dash" symbol](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-simple_dashed.html))

or extract the route data and use it to put icons at all the vertices on the polyline (like the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432765/how-in-google-maps-v3-set-polyline-with-points-which-link-lines-with-bold-dots/19436547#19436547), but with a transparent polyline)

[example of a custom DirctionsRenderer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html)

[markers every 2km on a Polyline](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polyline_example_kmmarkers_0.html)

[markers at 2 arbitrary distances on a directions polyline](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html)